# Failed to get response content from BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, webdriver

I have tried to use BeautifulSoup to retrieve data of Mercedes-C-class from CarGurus like:

```
url1 = https://www.cargurus.com/Cars/inventorylisting/viewDetailsFilterViewInventoryListing.action?
       &showNegotiable=true&sourceContext=carGurusHomePageModel
       &entitySelectingHelper.selectedEntity2=c21239
       &entitySelectingHelper.selectedEntity=c6079

url2 = https://www.cargurus.com/Cars/inventorylisting/viewDetailsFilterViewInventoryListing.action?
       &showNegotiable=true&sourceContext=carGurusHomePageModel
       &entitySelectingHelper.selectedEntity2=c21239
       &entitySelectingHelper.selectedEntity=c6079#listing=260322671_isFeatured

response1 = requests.get(url1)
response2 = requests.get(url2)
```

Note url2 is the link of first item shown on the page url1
 (with suffix `#listing=260322671_isFeatured`) , there are a lot of details I want to scrape.

But `response1.content` and `response2.content` ended up with exactly same content.
I've tried different pages and different car models , all ended up with the same thing when I use bs4.

BTW I'm using MacBook, and I've read somewhere about using WebDriver for Mac OS like

```
driver = webdriver.Safari()
driver.get(URL)
```

Only in this way I can get access to the specific item page, but the session will be locked, which means I can not use loop for accessing multiple pages again and again ... so I went back to bs4, any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is loaded dynamically through Ajax/Json. But inspecting where the page is making connections, we can emulate them with `requests`:

```
url = '''https://www.cargurus.com/Cars/inventorylisting/viewDetailsFilterViewInventoryListing.action?
       &showNegotiable=true&sourceContext=carGurusHomePageModel
       &entitySelectingHelper.selectedEntity2=c21239
       &entitySelectingHelper.selectedEntity=c6079'''

listing_detail_url = 'https://www.cargurus.com/Cars/detailListingJson.action?inventoryListing={}&searchZip=&searchDistance=100&inclusionType=DEFAULT'

import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')

data = []
for a in soup.select('a[href^="#listing"]'):  # get all listings on the page
    listing_id = a['href'].split('=')[-1]

    json_data = requests.get(listing_detail_url.format(listing_id)).json()
    # print(json.dumps(json_data, indent=4)) # <-- uncomment this to print all data

    listing_title = json_data['listing']['listingTitle']
    price = json_data['listing']['price']
    make_name = json_data['listing']['makeName']
    model_name = json_data['listing']['modelName']
    # ... other data

    data.append( (listing_title, price, make_name, model_name ) )

# print the data
print('{:<80} {:<30} {:<30} {:<30}'.format('Title', 'Price', 'Brand', 'Model'))
for row in data:
    print('{:<80} {:<30} {:<30} {:<30}'.format(*row))
```

Prints:

```
Title                                                                            Price                          Brand                          Model                         
2009 Mercedes-Benz C-Class C 300 Sport - $8,000                                  8000.0                         Mercedes-Benz                  C-Class                       
2008 Mercedes-Benz C-Class C 300 Luxury - $3,500                                 3500.0                         Mercedes-Benz                  C-Class                       
2009 Mercedes-Benz C-Class C 300 Sport - $5,999                                  5999.0                         Mercedes-Benz                  C-Class                       
2007 Mercedes-Benz C-Class C 280 4MATIC Luxury AWD - $1,975                      1975.0                         Mercedes-Benz                  C-Class                       
2007 Mercedes-Benz C-Class C 230 Sport - $2,499                                  2499.0                         Mercedes-Benz                  C-Class                       
2009 Mercedes-Benz C-Class - $5,299                                              5299.0                         Mercedes-Benz                  C-Class                       
2009 Mercedes-Benz C-Class C 300 4MATIC Luxury - $6,499                          6499.0                         Mercedes-Benz                  C-Class                       
2008 Mercedes-Benz C-Class C 300 Luxury - $5,950                                 5950.0                         Mercedes-Benz                  C-Class                       
2008 Mercedes-Benz C-Class C 300 Luxury 4MATIC - $6,650                          6650.0                         Mercedes-Benz                  C-Class                       
2005 Mercedes-Benz C-Class C 230 Kompressor Supercharged Sedan - $2,995          2995.0                         Mercedes-Benz                  C-Class                       
2007 Mercedes-Benz C-Class C 230 Sport - $4,900                                  4900.0                         Mercedes-Benz                  C-Class                       
2008 Mercedes-Benz C-Class C 350 Sport - $6,400                                  6400.0                         Mercedes-Benz                  C-Class                       
2009 Mercedes-Benz C-Class C 300 4MATIC Luxury - $6,900                          6900.0                         Mercedes-Benz                  C-Class                       
2008 Mercedes-Benz C-Class C 300 Sport - $6,200                                  6200.0                         Mercedes-Benz                  C-Class                       
2007 Mercedes-Benz C-Class C 280 4MATIC Luxury AWD - $3,830                      3830.0                         Mercedes-Benz                  C-Class
```

Comment: Thank you! It works! Can I ask how and why did you make the listing_detail_url like that? I mean it's different from the link address returned by just clicking the car title

Comment: @ilovebroccoli When you click on the link, you can see in Firefox/Chrom network inspector, that the page isn't making requests to that link, but somewhere else - it is using Javascript to change it.